# adding a new user to list in c program

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, string-comparison

Im just trying to write a simple function to addd a friend to a UserAccount list. All the information is provided through the parameter. If the user is already in the list I do not need add him again but display records saying he is already in list. I wrote this piece of code. not sure if this is correct, any suggestion to improve the code? Does this work?

```
int add_friend(UserAccount* user, char Circle, UserAccount* friend)
{
    struct UserAccountNode *p;

    p = (struct UserAccountNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct UserAccountNode));

    while (p != NULL)
        if(stricmp(user, p->friend) == 0){

            p->next = head; // inserting at the beginning
            head = p;
        }
        else {

            printf("%d already exists", friend)
        };
}
```

Comment: Add `break;` in else part.

Comment: `if` *may* be missing `{}`

Comment: Did you try it ? Actually half of the code needed is missing.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have not because I didn't write the whole program to make the code above work. Im just supposed to write the piece of code above with how I think it should be. That's why I don't know if its correct

Comment: @user3315144: your piece of code if **completely** wrong. 1) you allocate space for one user with `p= malloc....`, and then you use that pointer as pointer to the list that is supposed to contain the list of users. 2) you do `strcmpi(user, p->friend)`, which is wrong, because `user` doesn't point to a string. 3) you dont use the `circle` parameter. 4) you ask questions without suppliying all the information needed, what is `UserAccount` ?

Comment: Hi @user3315144. Don't let the rather robust response from WhozCraig put you off - one of the downsides of putting code on the internet for review is that the criticism can be very honest indeed! However, I do agree that getting a good book on this topic will help you enormously - rather than edging towards a program that may be quite wrong, it's worth looking at simple examples that get it right, and learning what each part of each example does.

Answer (score 3):

"not sure if this is correct" - does it do what you intended it to do? if so, it *might* be correct; if not. well...

And no, its nowhere *near* correct. the list of things wrong make a decent case for scrapping **all of it**. Such things include (but are not limited to):

- You claim you want to conditionally add a new friend but only if they're not already in the list. Yet the *first* thing you do is allocate space for something you're not even sure you need yet?
- Your loop has no exit condition that can possibly be met (unless `malloc()` actually *fails*). At no time is `p`, the only exit condition argument, *ever* assigned to *anything* after the first line in the function, which assigns it a dynamic allocation you may not even need. I.e. You have an infinite loop.
- You're passing a `UserAccount*` to `stricmp` as the first parameter, which expects a `const char*`.
- You're comparing `p->friend` with `user`. But **you just allocated what `p` points to.** Its `friend` member is indeterminate, i.e. has no defined content, yet you're sending that undefined content to `stricmp()` to compare against the input parameter `user`. This invokes **undefined behavior**.
- The comparison logic is backwards. `stricmp()` returns 0 if the strings are case-insensitive **equal**; not different. You logic (even if you weren't invoking undefined behavior due to the prior item mentioned above) is at least *attempting* to add items to the list only if they're already present.
- After two iterations through the list, if by some miracle the if-expression evaluated to true twice, you have created a circular self-referencing node and orphaned any list you originally had into the abyss.
- You're sending `friend`, a `UserAccount*`, to `printf` with a `"%d"` format specifier. While this *likely* won't *crash* your program, it is none-the-less more undefined behavior. If you want to print a pointer value with `printf()` use `"%p"`
- The unused function parameters are honestly the *least* of your worries. They may not have been used, but on the plus side, they likewise weren't used *incorrectly*; something that cannot be said for `user` and `friend`.

I'm not going to shine you on about "good effort" or "nice try". There is no chance this code even *compiled*, and absolutely *zero* chance it could *ever* run correctly. You need to review the actual algorithm you're trying to implement, and *heavily* review usage of pointers and dynamic memory in C.

Answer (score 2):

You code has at least two problems:

1. `while (p != NULL)`

   If `p` is not `NULL`, this will be an infinite loop, because you do not change `p` in the loop body or use statements like `break` to jump out of it.
2. `stricmp(user, p->friend)`

   You are using an uninitialized variable, this

   ```
   p = (struct UserAccountNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct UserAccountNode));
   ```

   only allocated a structure, but you never initialize it before you use it in the `while` loop.

Other mistakes are possible, such as you never use the `friend` argument, the parameters to `stricmp()` may be wrong, and so on.