# Adding Nodes in Linked List

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to add users to a linked list. I have two structs and a method to add called add_friend that sets up the addition of the node. The program does not ask for user input but passes the info through parameters in the add_friend method: In addition to adding the node (user) to the list I have to check if user already exists. I am getting an error when I try to compare string to see if the user exists. Any help? Unfortunately C is my weakest programming language, Im having a hard time understanding the pointers

```
struct UserAccountNode {
    struct UserAccount* content;
    char circle;
    struct UserAccountNode* next;

} *head = NULL;

struct UserAccount {
    char username[255];
    char lastnm [256];
    char firstnm[256];
    char password[256];
    char gender;
    int phone;
    struct Post* post_list;
    struct UserAccountNode* friend_list;
};

int add_friend(UserAccount* user, char Circle, UserAccount* Friend) {
    struct UserAccountNode* friend_list;

    friend_list = (struct UserAccountNode* ) malloc (sizeof(struct UserAccountNode));

    while (friend_list != NULL)
        if (stricmp(Circle, head->friend_list) == 0) {
            friend_list -> next = head;
            head = friend_list;
        } else { 
            printf("%d, User Already Exists", Friend);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is the aftermath of [the dissection of **this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627293/adding-a-new-user-to-list-in-c-program), you need to put down StackOverflow and pick up your text book.  Seriously. *Stop writing code and spend some time researching and reading it.* There is no short-cut to this.

Comment: How do you want to determine if the friend is already on the list?  Can you just check if a user with the same address is already present?

Answer (score 2):

The code does not compare strings. It compares `char` - Circle - with `UserAccountNode*` friend_list. But `stricmp` requires both arguments to be `const char *`. You have to do a loop through all items in `friend_list` and compare every `username` with a given one.

Another issue: you allocate memory for `UserAccountNode` but do not allocate memory for its internal field `UserAccount* content`. It may crash the application when you try to read the data.

Answer (score 2):

type of `Circle` is `char` not `char*`,
type of `head->friend_list` is `UserAccountNode*`.

So, you try to compare non-string objects as strings here:

`if (stricmp(Circle, head->friend_list) == 0)`

I think your program can't be compiled.